# Add images and start scrolling horizontal after filling max width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a mosaic composed of squared tiles (`img` tags). I am building it line by line (`ng-repeat` with Angular).
I want to set `max-height` and `max-width` of the mosaic area and when overflowing I need to scroll.

Vertically, it is working. Horizontally it is not; in fact, when the room for images ends, the next image goes to a new line.

I am into a Bootstrap column.

Here's my code HTML code:

```
<div class="mosaic-container">
  <span ng-repeat="line in mosaic.lines" class="mosaic-line">
    <span ng-repeat="element in line" class="mosaic-square">
      <img ng-src="mosaic_{{coordinates}}.jpeg" class="mosaic-image">
    </span>
    <br>
  </span>
</div>
```

and CSS code:

```
.mosaic-container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 520px;
  max-width: 730px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.mosaic-line {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.mosaic-square {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.mosaic-image {
  max-width: 42px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```